# Bounding the maximum difference of a binomial sum?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $X_k$, $k= 1, \dots, n$ denote independent Bernoulli random variables supported on $\{0, 1\}$ with parameter $p = 1/2$. Form $S_k = \sum_{j = 1}^k X_j$ and denote by 
$R_{j, r} = S_{j + r} - S_j$. How can I bound (for $t \geq 0$) the following probability as tightly as possible from above?
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{\max_{0 \leq j \leq (n - r)} R_{j, r} \geq t \right\}
$$